# get_extra_kwargs methon in ModelSerializer has no influence for read_only parameter of nested serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to allow manipulate with nested object with serializer only when object is created. But With following code nested `input` and `output` fields are still appear in html form (but without nested fields) and throw `"error": "{'output': ['This field is required.'], 'input': ['This field is required.']}"` when I try to update the only adjustable `status` field

[image]

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    input = InputSerializer()
    output = OutputSerializer()

    def get_extra_kwargs(self):

        extra_kwargs = super().get_extra_kwargs()
        _request = self.context['view'].request
        all_fields = (
            'id',
            'input',
            'output',
            'status',
        )
        adjustable_fields = []
        if _request.method == 'PUT':
            _rs = _request.parser_context['kwargs'].get('random_string')
            if _rs:
                adjustable_fields = [
                    'status',
                ]
            elif _request.user.is_staff:
                adjustable_fields = [
                    'input',
                    'status',
                    'custom_rate',
                    'custom_min_profit',
                    'custom_service_fee_percent'
                ]
            else:
                adjustable_fields = []
        extra_kwargs.update({x: {'read_only': True} for x in all_fields if x not in adjustable_fields})
        return extra_kwargs
```

**UPD**
I'm not logged in in the sample

Comment: [Per the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/?q=get_extra_kwargs#additional-keyword-arguments): _Please keep in mind that, if the field has already been explicitly declared on the serializer class, then the `extra_kwargs` option will be ignored._ I wonder if this is the issue you are running into.